# How to handle multiple checkbox in listview

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, adaptor

I've got a listview containing checkbox, text ...

My problem is with the checkbox, i've got a list of Objects (models) that are coming from my local database, i've got a boolean in my model which is telling me if i need to check or not the checkbox at the moment i build the listview. My problem is from the moment i check one box, the next time i'm coming to that view, all the checkbox will be checked, or unchecked ...

I first thaught that i had a problem with my list of models, but they are all correct ... i have no idea why ...

Here is the getView method of the adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder allItems = null;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        allItems = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        allItems.delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteItem);
        allItems.chkTick = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        allItems.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameItem);
        allItems.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceItem);
        allItems.numberItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberItem);
        allItems.plus = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plusItem);
        allItems.minus = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minusItem);
        convertView.setTag(allItems);
    }
    else
        allItems = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    final int pos = position;
    allItems.txtName.setText(this._sqlHelper.getItemById(items.get(position).getItemId()).getName());
    allItems.numberItem.setText(Integer.toString(items.get(position).getQuantity()));
    allItems.chkTick.setChecked(items.get(position).getIsChecked());
    if (tmp != null && tmp.compareTo("TRUE") == 0)
    {
        allItems.price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        allItems.price.setText("(" + Double.toString(items.get(position).getPrice()) + "€)");
    }
    else
        allItems.price.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    allItems.chkTick.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           items.get(pos).setIsChecked(isChecked);
           getPos(buttonView);
           if (isChecked)
           {
               if (tmp != null && tmp.compareTo("TRUE") == 0)
                   ShowPopup(activity, p, pos);
           }
           _sqlHelper.updateShoppingListItem(items.get(pos));
       }
    });
    allItems.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListItemsAdaptor.this.activity);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle("Delete Item");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item ?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Update", null);
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    _sqlHelper.deleteShoppingListItemByIdItem(items.get(pos).getListId(), items.get(pos).getItemId());
                    items.remove(pos);
                    updateResults(items);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
    allItems.plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            items.get(pos).setQuantity(items.get(pos).getQuantity()+ 1);
            updateResults(items);
            _sqlHelper.updateShoppingListItem(items.get(pos));
        }
    });
    allItems.minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (items.get(pos).getQuantity() > 1){
                items.get(pos).setQuantity(items.get(pos).getQuantity()- 1);
                updateResults(items);
                _sqlHelper.updateShoppingListItem(items.get(pos));
            }
        }
    });

    return (convertView);
}
```

Thank you for helping guys !

Answer (score 0):

I recomends that youuse a private ListArray checkedItems and add or remove in checked ones, after all, pass or use this list Array after the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method in your onCheckedChangeListener (and after every time you change the items)